# finding a counterexample about function as follows

Tags: functions

The following statement is false so I have to find a counterexample.

Statement: A function $f:A\to B$ is injective iff for all subset $C$ of $A$, $f(A \setminus C) \supseteq B\setminus f(C)$.

How to define $f$? What approach should I do?

Comment: Is it true that $B=f(A)$ ?

Comment: Oh, $f$ is not necessarily surjective hence $f(A) \ne B$.

Comment: Take $A=B=\mathbb{R}$, $C=\{0\}$, and $f(x)=e^x$. Try and convince yourself that this is a counterexample to $\implies $

Comment: Okay, I'll try it.

Comment: For above example, then $f(C) = f(0) = e^0 = 1$. On the other hand, domain of $f(A \setminus C)$ is $\Bbb R$ without $1$. Is it true?

Comment: You should write $f(C)=\{1\}$. You aren't correct when you say $f(A - C)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ without $1$. That's what $B-f(C)$ equals.

Comment: Thus, $B\setminus f(C) = \Bbb R \setminus \{1\}$ and $f(A \setminus C) = \Bbb R^+ \setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: Yes. And notice here $f(A-C)$  doesn't contain $B-f(C)$

Comment: It's because the negative real numbers doesn't contain in $f(A-C)$ right?

Comment: In other word, $x<0$ doesn't contain in $f(A-C)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ right?